# Native color dialog box does not close on OK button

Tags: colorbox

I tried to use the line

Private Sub Cor1_Click()

```
Cor1= Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(1)
```

End Sub

and the dialog box does not close with its native OK.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm keeping the question, despite finding the answer, because I believe it is worth to understand what I found:

I used the button I created, to open the dialog box as the name of the variable to pass the value. Changed the variable name, and the dialog box now closes on OK button.

Private Sub Cor1_Click()

```
Dim Cor11 As Long
Cor11 = 0
Cor11 = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(1)
```

End Sub